# Hook into iOS spinner input with HTML5 app?

Tags: ios, html, forms, mobile

I'm currently building a HTML5 app. Is there a way to hook into the native iOS "spinner" which is used in the nativ timer app:

[image]

If this is not possible, are there any HTML5 libraries that offer this kind of input?

Comment: did you ever find anything?  I did a quick look at jqueryui - not there.  Its been 3 months since your post?

Comment: Haven't found anything - for the current project we just didn't use this kind of UI input. I guess it has to be a build form the ground up.